# undefined control sequence in equation

Tags: errors, equations

I have loaded the `amsmath` package. I am not able to get the mass function of a negative binomial distribution. 
The code is:

```
\begin{equation*}

f(count_{i,t}|\lambda_{i,t},\theta_i) = 
{\Gamma(\lambda_{i,t} + count_{i,t})/{\Gamma(\lambda_{i,t})\Gamma(count_{i,t}+1)}}{(\theta_i/{1+\theta_i})}^count_{i,t} {(1/{1+\theta_i})}^\lamba_{i,t}

\end{equation*}
```

The error is:

```
[14] [15] [16] [17]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.380 ...})}^count_{i,t} {(1/{1+\theta_i})}^\lamba
                                                  _{i,t}
```

[image: This is how I want the equation to look like] Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You have `\lamba` instead of `\lambda`.

Comment: And you cannot have empty lines in an `equation`.

Comment: You may also be missing curly braces, `{` and `}`, around the final `count_{i,t}` expression, which looks like it should be placed in a superscript (exponent) position. Incidentally, even after you've made the changes made in these comments, the equation is not going to look anything like the image you've posted since you're using inline-fraction expressions rather than `\frac`.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is your equation corrected:
\begin{equation*}
f(\mathrm{count}_{i,t}\mid\lambda_{i,t},\theta_i) = {\Gamma(\lambda_{i,t} + \mathrm{count}_{i,t})/{\Gamma(\lambda_{i,t})\Gamma(\mathrm{count}_{i,t}+1)}}{(\theta_i/{1+\theta_i})}^{\mathrm{count}_{i,t}}{(1/{1+\theta_i})}^{\lambda_{i,t}}
\end{equation*}
This is the equation from the image you've posted:
\begin{equation*}
f(y_{it}\mid\lambda_{it},\theta_i) = \frac{\Gamma(\lambda_{it} + y_{it})}{\Gamma(\lambda_{it})\Gamma(y_{it}+1)}\left(\frac{\theta_i}{1+\theta_i}\right)^{y_{it}}\left(\frac{1}{1+\theta_i}\right)^{\lambda_{it}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would also change `|` to `\mid `: doing so will create better spacing around the symbol.